# java- Check if file is successfully indexed and update table status

Tags: java, mysql

Let's say I want to index a file. The file is stored in a `filequeue` table. The table structure looks like below:

```
 UniqueID   FilePath                 Status     
 1          C:\Folder1\abc.pdf       Active
 2          C:\Folder1\def.pdf       Active
 3          C:\Folder1\efg.pdf       Error
```

There are four different status : Active, Processing, Success and Error

Active: When the file is inserted to the table pending for indexing process

Processing: When indexing process is starting, the table status is updated to Processing.

Success: After the indexing process is completed,table status should be updated to processing.

Error: If by any chance, the processing fail for some reason.

For some reason, let's say `abc.pdf` does not exist. And when I scan the table, it will retrieve all filepath with status = Active and starts iterating each one of them and do the index function. During this process, it will update the status to Processing and then to Complete if there are no issues.

However, it will throw an error `FileNotFoundException`
on `abc.pdf` which is fine since the file does not exist but it still updates the status to `Complete`. It should update to Error status instead.

I was thinking of using an if else statement and it looks like this:

```
 public void doScan_DB() throws Exception {
  boolean fileprocessstatus=false;
        try {


            Statement statement = con.connect().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from filequeue where Status='Active'");

            while (rs.next()) {
                // get the filepath of the PDF document
                String path1 = rs.getString(2);
                // while running the process, update status : Processing
                updateProcess_DB();

             // call the index function
                Indexing conn = new Indexing();
                conn.doScan(path1);

                fileProcessStatus =true;
                // After completing the process, update status: Complete
                if(fileProcessStatus=true){
                    updateComplete_DB();
                }else{

                    //call function to update status to error if index fails
                }




                }


        }catch(SQLException|IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

my DoScan() method:

```
 public void doScan(String path) throws Exception{


     /*   File folder = new File("D:\\PDF1");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                //  HashSet<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<>();

                String path = "D:\\PDF1\\" + file.getName();*/
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(path))) {

            if (!document.isEncrypted()) {

                PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
                String lines[] = pdfFileInText.split("\\r?\\n");
                for (String line : lines) {
                    String[] words = line.split(" ");
                    // words.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", ""));


                    for (String word : words) {
                        // check if one or more special characters at end of string then remove OR
                        // check special characters in beginning of the string then remove
                        // uniqueWords.add(word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", ""));
                        list.add(word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", ""));
                        // uniqueWords.add(word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", ""));
                    }

                }


            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Exception while trying to read pdf document - " + e);

        }

        String[] words1 =list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        // String[] words2 =uniqueWords.toArray(new String[uniqueWords.size()]);

        // MysqlAccessIndex connection = new MysqlAccessIndex();



        index(words1,path);


        System.out.println("Completed");



    }

}
```

UpdateError_DB() :

```
public void updateError_DB(){

        try{

            Statement statement = con.connect().createStatement();
            statement.execute("update filequeue SET STATUS ='Error' where STATUS ='Processing' ");

        }catch(Exception e){


            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

UpdateComplete_DB():

```
public void updateComplete_DB() {

        try {

            Statement statement = con.connect().createStatement();
            statement.execute("update filequeue SET STATUS ='Complete' where STATUS ='Processing' ");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


    }
```

However, it doesn't really fix the issue of update the status correctly.
Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution based on my understanding of your scenario.

**doScan_DB()** method:

```
    public void doScan_DB() throws Exception {
            boolean fileprocessstatus = false;
            try {

                    Statement statement = con.connect().createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from filequeue where Status='Active'");

                    while (rs.next()) {
                            //Get the uniqueID of active filepath
                            String uniqueID = rs.getString(1);
                            // get the filepath of the PDF document
                            String path1 = rs.getString(2);

                            // while running the process, update status : Processing
                            updateProcess_DB(uniqueID);

                            // call the index function
                            Indexing conn = new Indexing();
                            if (conn.doScan(path1)) {
                                    updateComplete_DB(uniqueID);
                            } else {
                                    updateError_DB(uniqueID);
                            }

                    }

            } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

            }
    }
```

**doScan()** method:

```
  public boolean doScan(String path) {

            /*
             * File folder = new File("D:\\PDF1"); File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
             * 
             * for (File file : listOfFiles) { if (file.isFile()) { // HashSet<String>
             * uniqueWords = new HashSet<>();
             * 
             * String path = "D:\\PDF1\\" + file.getName();
             */
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            boolean isSuccess = true;
            try {
                    File f = new File(path);
                    if (!f.exists()) {
                            isSuccess = false;
                    } else {
                            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(f);
                            if (!document.isEncrypted()) {

                                    PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                                    String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
                                    String lines[] = pdfFileInText.split("\\r?\\n");
                                    for (String line : lines) {
                                            String[] words = line.split(" ");
                                            // words.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", ""));

                                            for (String word : words) {
                                                    // check if one or more special characters at end of string then
                                                    // remove OR
                                                    // check special characters in beginning of the string then
                                                    // remove
                                                    // uniqueWords.add(word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", ""));
                                                    list.add(word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", ""));
                                                    // uniqueWords.add(word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", ""));
                                            }

                                    }

                            }
                    }
                    String[] words1 = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
                    // String[] words2 =uniqueWords.toArray(new String[uniqueWords.size()]);

                    // MysqlAccessIndex connection = new MysqlAccessIndex();

                    index(words1, path);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Exception while trying to read pdf document - " + e);
                    isSuccess = false;
            }
            return isSuccess;
    }
```

Now all the update methods.Here I'll be using JDBC **PreparedStatement** in place of JDBC **Statement**. I'm assuming your UniqueId is of **Int** type.

**Note:** Make necessary changes according to your environment

```
    public void updateComplete_DB(String uniqueID) {

    try {
         String sql="UPDATE filequeue SET STATUS ='Complete' WHERE STATUS ='Processing' AND UniqueID=?";
         PreparedStatement statement = con.connect().prepareStatement(sql);

         statement.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(uniqueID));
         int rows = statement.executeUpdate();
         System.out.prrintln("No. of rows updated:"+rows)

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


}


public void updateProcess_DB(String uniqueID) {

    try {
         String sql="UPDATE filequeue SET STATUS ='Processing' WHERE UniqueID=?";
         PreparedStatement statement = con.connect().prepareStatement(sql);

         statement.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(uniqueID));
         int rows = statement.executeUpdate();
         System.out.prrintln("No. of rows updated:"+rows)

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


}
public void updateError_DB(String uniqueID) {

    try {
         String sql="UPDATE filequeue SET STATUS ='Error' WHERE STATUS ='Processing' AND UniqueID=?";
         PreparedStatement statement = con.connect().prepareStatement(sql);

         statement.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(uniqueID));
         int rows = statement.executeUpdate();
         System.out.prrintln("No. of rows updated:"+rows)

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


}
```